# Scientist couple raises alien baby

Tags: story-identification, movie

A science fiction movie where a scientist couple secretly raises a female alien baby. The baby has a tail, and grows into an adult in a matter of months (or weeks). During adolescence, she starts becoming aggressive toward the woman scientist. IIRC, it was a competition thing in order to mate with the man.

Somehow, the man ends up dead, the alien changes her sex from female to male, rapes the woman and impregnates her. At the end of the film, the woman is about nine months pregnant and signing away the rights to the alien/human baby for experimentation purposes. What's the name of the movie?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall any more details you can [edit] into your question.

Answer (score 29):

I think this is the 2009 French-Canadian film *[Splice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splice_(film))*.

[image]

The baby is not an alien, it's a genetic hybrid created by scientists who then attempt to conceal it's existence by raising it themselves. Otherwise, it matches all the details you described.

Comment: I thought the man and the hybrid had relations, but maybe I remember that wrong.

Comment: @JPhi1618 According to the Wikipedia article summarizing the plot, the man and the hybrid did have relations...